# How to elegantly split a vector of consecutive integers into k groups (as list elements) in R? Group should be as equally sized as possible

Tags: r, vector, grouping, sequence

Let's assume I have a vector containing integers from 1 to 100.

```
> 1:100
  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
 [25]  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48
 [49]  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72
 [73]  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96
 [97]  97  98  99 100
```

I would like to divided these, say, into seven groups. While the group sizes won't be equal (100 is not divisible by 7), I would like to the groups to be as equally sized as possible (some will have 14 and some will have 15 elements).

Is there an elegant way (a function perhaps) available to do this?